# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException no JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

### Estou com um problema na hora que carregar um arquivo com o método FXMLLoader, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho esse problema quando faço uma tela sem usar um arquivo FXML, alguém sabe o porquê do erro?

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente está faltando adicionar os módulos do JavaFX.

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx